# model.summary() and plot_model() showing nothing from the built model in tensorflow.keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am testing something which includes building a `FCNN` network **Dynamically**. Idea is to build Number of layers and it's neurons based on a given list and the dummy code is:

```
neurons = [10,20,30] # First Dense has 10 neuron, 2nd has 20 and third has 30

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(1024,))
x = Dense(10,activation='relu')(inputs)

for n in neurons:
  x = Dense(n,activation='relu')(x)

out = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs,out)
model.summary()
keras.utils.plot_model(model,'model.png')
for layer in model.layers:
  print(layer.name)
```

To my surprise, it is showing nothing.I even compiled and ran the functions again and nothing came out.

The `model.summary` always shows number of trainable and non trainable params but not the model structure and layer names. Why is this happening? Or is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `model.summary()`, don't mix `tf 2.x` and standalone [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) at a time. If I ran you model in `tf 2.x`, I get the expected results.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import Model 
from tensorflow import keras 

# your code ...
model.summary()
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 1024)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                10250     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                110       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 20)                220       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 30)                630       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 31        
=================================================================
Total params: 11,241
Trainable params: 11,241
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________
```

About plotting the model, there is a couple of option that can be used while you plot your [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) model. Here is one example:

```
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_dtype=True, 
                       show_layer_names=True, show_shapes=True,  
                       to_file='model.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! my bad! If accidentally used `keras.model`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: glad to help. :)